# Linux cp with variables

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I'd like to copy a file that is specified by a variable in a Linux `bash` file.

This is how it does *not* work:

```
molecules = (1butene E2butene)
for molecule in ${molecules[*]}
do
    ### some stuff (works)
    formchk $molecule.chk $molecule.fchk
    ### cp doesn't work
    cp $molecule.com ${molecule}_scan.com
done
```

any ideas?

EDIT: it does also not work when I remove the spaces arround "=". cp throws no error, but I dont get a second file that is named molecule_scan.com

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net to fix the syntax issues in your script

Comment: @user7408924 please ensure that you can reproduce the problem with the minimal example you have posted in the question. If you are seeing any specific errors, please add those to your question.

Comment: Does your script, by any chance, have DOS line endings? See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info, under "Before asking about problematic code"

Comment: no it doesn't, but my first line is #!/usr/bin/env zsh (I expanded an example to submit a job on our universities computer, so I kept that as it was) could that be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

The main problem that I can see is the spaces around the `=` in your assignment:

```
molecules=(1butene E2butene)
for molecule in "${molecules[@]}"
do
  ### some stuff (works)
  formchk "$molecule.chk" "$molecule.fchk"
  ### cp doesn't work
  cp "$molecule.com" "${molecule}_scan.com"
done
```

Other things that I have changed are to use `@` instead of `*`, to expand the array into a list of words for the loop. I've also added quotes around all of the variable expansions, which though unnecessary in this specific case, is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the blanks in the assignment:

```
molecules=(1butene E2butene)
```

The shell delimits words at white spaces and assignments must read `name=value`.

Note that in your specific case you don't need non-standard shell arrays. Simply write

```
molecules="1butene E2butene"
for molecule in $molecules
do
  ### some stuff (works)
  formchk $molecule.chk $molecule.fchk
  ### cp doesn't work
  cp $molecule.com ${molecule}_scan.com
done
```

If you have trouble figuring out why something in the script does not work as expected, you can trace execution by adding a line with `set -x` before the rest of the script.

Comment: thanks for your answer. still does not work :/ could it be something with the read/write rights?

Comment: @user7408924 Please state exactly what it is that does not work, e.g. an error message. Could it be that there is no `$molecule.com` file to copy? What is the result/effect of running `formchk`?

Comment: I expect to have two files afterwards for each molecule. 1butene.com and 1butene_scan.com. However, I dont get the second file. there definetly is a file 1butene.com and no error with set -x;
formchk simply converts the other file. i put it there as an example to show that the loop works in principle

Comment: If someone tags their question `bash`, it's fair to assume they're not worried about portability. Changing the approach from a Bash array (robust, if done right) to a fragile solution based on an unquoted (scalar) variable reference whose value is subject to word-splitting and globbing strikes me as a step backward, especially if the only hint at trouble is "in your specific case".

Comment: @user7408924 Then what error does the `cp` produce? Permission denied? No space left on device? File not found?

Comment: no error, i just dont get the 2nd file :/ (the error would be displayed if I put set -x, correct?)

Comment: @user7408924 No, set -x just displays each command before it is executed. What does it display for the `cp` command? Does it display `cp 1butene.com _scan.com`?

Comment: @Jens nope, 1butene.com 1butene_scan.com

Answer (score -2):

seems like it was a problem with the underscore
this works:

```
cp $molecule.com ${molecule}\_scan.com
```

Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: If your shell is really Bash and you're using the standard `cp` utility on Linux, adding `\ ` should make no difference whatsoever.

Comment: This certainly was not the problem. There's something you are not telling us. Did you forget the curly braces? Because `cp $molecule.com $molecule_scan.com` actually results in `cp 1butene.com .com` being run. Do you have a `.com` file lying around?

Comment: no the braces are there and there is the 1butene.com file

Comment: @Jens one thing that I didn't mention is that I am using my linux terminal to connect to the universities computer and the file es executed on that computer. my heading is #!/usr/bin/env zsh. maybe that can help?

Comment: @user7408924: If your script's first line is `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` and you execute your script directly, it is executed by `zsh`, and `bash` doesn't come into play. However, even in `zsh` `cp $molecule.com ${molecule}_scan.com` should work just fine. Adding the `\ ` doesn't hurt, but should make no difference.